# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.mixture.gmm'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am getting the following error when trying to perform Voice Authentication

I have tried in Jupyter notebook and Spyder, but unable to resolve the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-df29f49ded81> in <module>
    158 
    159 if __name__ == '__main__':
--> 160     recognize()

<ipython-input-13-df29f49ded81> in recognize()
     42                 os.listdir(modelpath) if fname.endswith('.gmm')]
     43 
---> 44     models    = [pickle.load(open(fname,'rb')) for fname in gmm_files]
     45 
     46     speakers   = [fname.split("/")[-1].split(".gmm")[0] for fname 

<ipython-input-13-df29f49ded81> in <listcomp>(.0)
     42                 os.listdir(modelpath) if fname.endswith('.gmm')]
     43 
---> 44     models    = [pickle.load(open(fname,'rb')) for fname in gmm_files]
     45 
     46     speakers   = [fname.split("/")[-1].split(".gmm")[0] for fname
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.mixture.gmm'

I don't understand where am lacking to understand the code.
Can u please help me

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same version when I was working on a voice recognition project.
You must've installed the latest version of scikit-learn, for which the code doesn't work. Downgrade you scikit-learn version to the version given by the owner or `scikit-learn==0.19.2` worked for me.

To uninstall and re-install run these two commands:

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn (to uninstall)
pip install scikit-learn==0.19.2 (to install again) this will surely help
```

dont try for version 0.18.1

Answer (score 1):

Another option that also works, besides downgrading your version of `scikit-learn`, is to print all the elements `sklearn.mixture` contains in the newest version. For example:

```
from sklearn import mixture
print(help(mixture))
```

By doing this I was able to see that in the current version of `scikit-learn` (1.0.1), instead of calling `mixture.GMM`, you need to call `mixture.GaussianMixture`. This is the corresponding documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is generic, solves this question, plus solves a whole lot of other scenarios where this might arise, like unpickling a pickle object written using an older version of scikit learn while having a new version of scikit-learn.